# Check to see if file changes then insert into database

Tags: php, xml

Im working on a project that will collect data from XML files and write them to a database. I have a script set up that will be run via a cron job to go though the list of XML files and write the ones that have a newer date to the database so that I have a record of the xml files. I have the timestamp of the last insert for each record in the database. However I'm running into an issue with my logic when trying to accomplish my goal. Any assistance would be great. Im getting an error that says Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in aeiArchive.php on line 37 Ill denote line 37 in my code.

```
$readers= glob("AEI/*xml");

if (is_array($readers)) {
    foreach ($readers as $reader) {
//This will have to be edidted to look at more than one file. 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($reader) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$timestamp = date("m/d/y H:i:s", filemtime($reader));
//Foreach Loop for the AEI Report from the AEI reader
foreach ($xml->xpath("//AEI_Report") as $aei_info){
    $totalaxles=(string)$aei_info->totalaxles;
    $totaltons=(string)$aei_info->totaltons;
    $trainspeedmph=(string)$aei_info->trainspeedmph;
    $totalloads=(string)$aei_info->totalloads;
    $totalmtys=(string)$aei_info->totalmtys;
    $trainsymbol=(string)$aei_info->trainsymbol;
    $scannername=(string)$aei_info->scannername;
    //$reportdata=(string)$aei_info->repoartdata;
    $sqlf = "SELECT insert_time FROM aei_log WHERE aei_scanner_name = ?";
    $stmtf = $conn->prepare($sqlf);
    $stmtf->bind_param("s", $scannername);
    $stmtf->execute();
    $resultf = $stmtf->get_result();
    while ($row = $resultf->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row['insert_time'];
    }
    if ($timestamp >= $row['insert_time']) { //Line 37
    die();
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO aei_log (aei_scanner_name, aei_train_symbol, aei_train_speed, aei_axles, aei_lds, aei_mtys, aei_tons, insert_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        //echo $conn->error;
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $scannername, $trainsymbol, $trainspeedmph, $totalaxles, $totalloads, $totalmtys, $totaltons, $timestamp);
        $stmt->execute();
        $last_id = $stmt->insert_id;
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if (isset($result)){
            $affectedRow ++;
        }else{
            $error_message = mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
        }

}

//Foreach Loop for the train data from the AEI reader
foreach ($xml->xpath("//AEI_Report_UnitData") as $traininfo){
    $roadname=(string)$traininfo->roadname;
    $unitnumber=(int)$traininfo->unitnumber;
    $equipmentype=(string)$traininfo->equipmentype;
    $isloaded=(string)$traininfo->isloaded;     
    
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO aei_unit_data (aei_uid, aei_tr_eqpt, /*aei_tr_dir, aei_tr_seq,*/ aei_tr_rdnm, aei_tr_untnum, aei_tr_lded/*, aei_tr_dest*/) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        echo $conn->error;
        $stmt->bind_param("issss", $last_id, $equipmentype, $roadname, $unitnumber, $isloaded);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if (isset($result)){
            $affectedRow ++;
        }else{
            $error_message = mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
        }
        
    }

}
}
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem? What error do you get?

Comment: Im getting an error that says Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in aeiArchive.php on line 37 Ill denote line 37 in my code.

Comment: Normally the system will throw such an error when there is no value on say the index of an array or something like that. Did you check the existence of the data (e.g. use isset) before doing processing in your line 37 ?

Comment: @KenLee I added this above line 37 if (!isset($row['insert_time'])) {
  echo "error";
 }else{ 
and it output error, but if I echo out the row in the while loop it shows the data from the database

Comment: why are you looping there in line 34- 36 ? why not simple extract the `$row = $resultf->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: MaxMuster is right. `while ($row = $resultf->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row['insert_time'];}` seems not meaningful. What is the purpose of the line **$row['insert_time'];** ?? (not an output, not a comparison, not an assignment .... ?)

Comment: Ok eliminating the while loop fixed one problem, but now its still pulling the data of files that havent changed making duplicates which is not how it's intended to work

Comment: In my experience, after you have processed a XML file (insert into the db), then you should remove the file (or at least move it to another directory) so that the same file will not be re-processed. Otherwise in the long run your script will process those "processed" data which will (1) make duplicates (2) be wasting time.

Comment: @KenLee I don't have that option unfortuneitly, a program generates the XML file automaticly and can't be removed. Can i compaire the file modified time in the xml to the time string that was entered in the database?

Comment: In that case usually I will insert the filename (which data has been processed) into a small database table, so that next time when I read the XML files again I will check whether the filename exists in that table, and will skip its processing if it does.

Comment: That wont work either, the XML file gets updated with the same filename but has different data in it. That's why im trying to compare the dates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236015/discussion-between-ken-lee-and-david).

Comment: @KenLee I went to the chat but there was no one there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to rewirte some of my code to provide the desired outcome. Below are those changes.

```
$resultTime = "";//$result time is the time stored stored on the database 
while ($row = $resultf->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultTime = $row['insert_time'];
    }
    if (!isset($resultf)) {
        echo "error";
    }else{
    if ($timestamp > $resultTime) { //Line 37
```